# Recover deleted folder from user/library

Tags: data-recovery

I have accidentally deleted a folder `/Users/me/Library/Application Support/Postgres/` through the use of a third party uninstall app (CleanMyMac). Is this folder gone forever or can I recover it? I haven't restarted the system. The folder contains the postgres db and I don't run time machine, I have a backup of the db but it's old so would like to recover if i can

Comment: Is it still in your Trash?

Comment: It never was, i assume system library files deleted via an uninstall get put elsewhere

Comment: Maybe CleanMyMac removes them directly then. Changes for recovery are rather small then, especially if you kept using your computer afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if a third party file recovery software can find the directories

Comment: Add that file to your daily backup...

Comment: Or use time machine to get an hourly backup

Comment: Actually don't add that file to your normal backup - a simple file backup does not work well on databases. postgres does include backup utilities use them daily.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from CleanMyMac is that it permanently destroys this, I tested two file recovery software options and neither found the old library fodlers

Answer (score 0):

**Q: Is this folder gone forever or can I recover it?**

Files with no backup or other copy are lost forever when deleted. It might be possible to use some disk recovery software on a hard drive, if the blocks haven't been overwritten; but recovery chances are much reduced on SSDs.

This shows the dangers of: a) not backing up your data and b) using 'cleaning' apps.